# Is the TextChanged Event not triggered by a TextBox in TextMode="Password"?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a password text field that shows/hides password requirements as the user types their password into a TextBox with TextMode="Password". I added a TextChanged event so I could check the TextBox text against the requirements each time a new character is typed/removed.
The problem I am having is that the TextChanged event is seemingly not being triggered ever. Here is the relevant code:

```html
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="BoldLabel14px" Font-Bold="True" 
                   Text="New Password"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" Font-Names="calibri" 
                      Font-Size="14px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
</tr>
```

```vb
Protected Sub NewPassword_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewPassword.TextChanged
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NewPassword Text = " & Me.NewPassword.Text)
        CheckPasswordRequirements(Me.NewPassword.Text)
        Me.PasswordRequirementsCapital.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

From this code, the output never shows the debug statement as the TextBox is modified. Is different way to grab the text as it is written? I am using Visual Studio, vb.net, and asp.net.

Comment: This is great @Çöđěxěŕ but do you know any way to trigger the event as the text is being changed, not after?

Comment: Okie dokie, in that case, this is solved! Thank you @Çöđěxěŕ !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason the event isn't fired is because you don't have an event tied up to even be fired.

It should be something like:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" Font-Names="calibri" Font-Size="14px" TextMode="Password" ontextchanged="NewPassword_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

The event itself will not fire until you leave though, it's a server side process and only happens between posts to the server. If you want to handle this as the text is changing look into `JavaScript` and or `JQuery`.